# How to get Attributes from DOMElement

Tags: php, dom

I have this DOMElement.

I have two questions:

1) What means object value omitted?

2) How can I get the attributes from this DOMElement?

```
 object(DOMElement)#554 (18) {
        ["tagName"]=>
        string(5) "input"
        ["schemaTypeInfo"]=>
        NULL
        ["nodeName"]=>
        string(5) "input"
        ["nodeValue"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["nodeType"]=>
        int(1)
        ["parentNode"]=>
        string(22) "(object value omitted)"
        ["childNodes"]=>
        string(22) "(object value omitted)"
        ["firstChild"]=>
        NULL
        ["lastChild"]=>
        NULL
        ["previousSibling"]=>
        string(22) "(object value omitted)"
        ["nextSibling"]=>
        string(22) "(object value omitted)"
        ["attributes"]=>
        string(22) "(object value omitted)"
        ["ownerDocument"]=>
        string(22) "(object value omitted)"
        ["namespaceURI"]=>
        NULL
        ["prefix"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["localName"]=>
        string(5) "input"
        ["baseURI"]=>
        NULL
        ["textContent"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
```

I have made this class to access the object. The purpose of this is so that I can get the type attribute from an input field.

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

class Field
{
    /**
     * @var \DOMElement
     */
    protected $node;

    public function __construct($node){
        $this->node = $node;
    }

    public function getNode(){
        return $this->node;
    }

    public function getTagName(){

        foreach ($this->node as $value) {
            return $value->tagName;
        }
    }

    public function getAttribute(){


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I believe `(object value omitted)` is just some internal `DOM` or `var_dump()` restriction, to prevent dumping too deep and/or dumping recursive information about the object graph.
2. Then, about getting information about attributes:

   - To get *all* attributes of a [`DOMElement`](https://secure.php.net/manual/class.domelement.php), you would use the [`attributes`](https://secure.php.net/manual/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.attributes) property, which is defined on its parent class [`DOMNode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/class.domnode.php) and returns a [`DOMNamedNodeMap`](https://secure.php.net/manual/class.domnamednodemap.php) with [`DOMAttr`](https://secure.php.net/manual/class.domattr.php) nodes:

     ```php
     // $this->node must be a DOMElement, otherwise $attributes will be NULL
     $attributes = $this->node->attributes;

     // then, to loop through all attributes:
     foreach( $attributes as $attribute ) {
       // do something with $attribute (which will be a DOMAttr instance)
     }
     // or, perhaps like so:
     for( $i = 0; $i < $attributes->length; $i++ ) {
       $attribute = $attributes->item( $i );
       // do something with $attribute (which will be a DOMAttr instance)
     }

     // to get a single attribute from the map:
     $typeAttribute = $attributes->getNamedItem( 'type' );
     // (which will be a DOMAttr instance or NULL if it doesn't exist)
     ```
   - To get just one attribute, named `type` from a `DOMElement`, you could use:

     - [`DOMElement::getAttributeNode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/domelement.getattributenode.php), to get a`DOMAttr` node that represents the `type` attribute, like so:

       ```php
       $typeAttr = $this->node->getAttributeNode( 'type' );
       // (which will be NULL if it doesn't exist)
       ```

       or
     - [`DOMElement::getAttribute()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/domelement.getattribute.php), to get the string value of the attribute `type`, like so:

       ```php
       $typeAttrValue = $this->node->getAttribute( 'type' );
       // (which will an empty string if it doesn't exist)
       ```